# Time-dependent metadata in xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have the need to store metadata in my `xarray.Dataset` that varies along one dimension (specifically, `time`). In my particular scenario, the Dataset is a stack of satellite images over time. The metadata in question is the orbit direction (ascending vs descending), orbit number, etc. I need to be able to select slices of the Dataset based on this metadata.

As far as I know, the metadata implementation via `attrs` only supports setting attributes for a whole Dataset (or DataArray).

The only way I can think of to deal with this is to encode the metadata into a variable, but this would require one additional variable for *every* metadata item that varies with time. It also just doesn't feel quite right as the variables in my opinion should contain *data*, not *metadata*, and many operations (like taking the mean) wouldn't make any sense.

What would be the best way to store time-dependent metadata?